# Javascript not working after closing/reopening modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I'm having an issue with using javascript files within a bootstrap modal in a yii2 project I am working on. I have a modal box with the view used for the body of the modal being loaded through ajax. In one of the views I have registered a javascript file to disable certain form inputs depending on a few conditions. The first time I load the modal, the javascript functions without any issues. However, if I close the modal and reopen it, the javascript is no longer working until I refresh the entire page.

I've tried clearing out the content of the modal entirely using

```
$("#modal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(e){
    var contentArea = $(this).find('#modalContent');
    contentArea.html('');
});
```

but it the javascript still does not function upon reopening the modal.

This is the code that defines the modal

```
<?php 
  Modal::begin([
    'header'=>'<h4>Event</h4>',
    'id'=>'modal',
    'size'=>'modal-lg',
    'options'=>[
        'tabindex'=>false
    ]
  ]);
?>
  <div id="modalContent"></div>
<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

And the page being loaded into the modal...

```
<?php
  $this->registerJsFile('@web/js/registration.js');
?>
<div class="registrant-create">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
   'id'=>$model->formName(),
   'action'=>['create-payment'],
   'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
   'validationUrl'=>['/event/registrant/validate-registrant','event_id'=>$model->event_id],
   'options'=>['data-pjax'=>true],
]); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="form_page" value="level" id="form_page" />
<div id="page-level">
    <?=$this->render('_form_level', [
        'form' => $form,
        'model' => $model,
        'model_code'=>$model_code,
        'list_levels' => $list_levels,
        'list_members' => $list_members,
    ])?>
</div>
<div id="page-attendee">
    <?=$this->render('_form_attendee', [
        'form' => $form,
        'model' => $model,
        'model_organization' => $model_organization,
        'models_attendee' => $models_attendee,
        'models_personal' => $models_personal,
        'models_personalEmail' => $models_personalEmail,
        'models_email' => $models_email,
        'models_answer' => $models_answer,
    ]);?>
</div>
```

The sub-views being rendered contain the fields for the individual form pages (theres 4 in total, cut it down to keep it readable). An example of one of the subviews would be...

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    Instructions... 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'level_id',['options'=>['class'=>'col-lg-5']])->dropDownList($list_levels['items'],['options'=>$list_levels['attributes']])->label("Select a level"); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model_code, 'code',['options'=>['class'=>'col-lg-5']])->label("Enter a registration code")?>
</div>
<?= $form->field($model, 'member_id','inputOptions'=>['data-disabled'=>true]])->dropDownList($list_members)->label("Select a member"); ?>


<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::button('Continue', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg form-continue', 'data-next'=>'attendee'])?>
</div>
```

Is there something I need to do to reload the javascript file? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: provide your HTML

Comment: @AKA Any part of it in particuluar?

Comment: HTML of the popup modal

Comment: added HTML to the original post

Comment: have you checked you console to see if it is reporting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '#modal' , function(e){
    var contentArea = $(this).find('#modalContent');
    contentArea.html('');
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so that one can understand why it works

Comment: javascript and jquery event not working on append items that comes from ajax normally if u want to make it work you should use it like this..